# Ruby on Rails | Binding View form to model/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This view is rendered as a partial, in a :show sidebar of other module/objects

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  get '/', to: 'application#index'
  resources :commands
end
```

_command.html.erb:

note the form_for, some variances I've tried, with their errors:

When its: form_for @command
Error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

When its: form_for Command.new
Error: `uninitialized constant CommandsController`

```
<% @modName = locals[:moduleName] %>
<% @id = locals[:id] %>
<%= form_for Command.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:Code, Command.where(FLD: @modName), :Code, :Definition, options ={prompt: true}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateSubMod(this.value)"}) %>
    <br /><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant controller snippet:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Command do
  menu false

  all_fields = Commands.fields
  all_fields = all_fields + [:mod, :id, :submod]
  permit_params all_fields 
  field_special = Commands.types
  
  controller do
    def new
      @command = Command.new
      @resource = Command.new
    end
  end
```

Rake Routes:

```
GET              /commands(.:format)           commands#index
POST             /commands(.:format)           commands#create
new_command GET  /commands/new(.:format)       commands#new
edit_command GET /commands/:id/edit(.:format)  commands#edit
command GET      /commands/:id(.:format)       commands#show
PATCH            /commands/:id(.:format)       commands#update
PUT              /commands/:id(.:format)       commands#update
DELETE           /commands/:id(.:format)       commands#destroy
```

UPDATE: my (new) app/controllers/commands_controller.rb

```
class CommandsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @command = Command.new
    end
    
end
```

Any insight, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what "When form reads: form_for @command" means. Please [edit] your question to describe what actions the user performs that leads up to the error. Then show the full error message, not just one line from it.

Comment: do you have a `CommandsController` class defined in app/controllers/commands_controller.rb ?

Comment: In Rails the only time you should ever be using capital letters is for ClassNames and CONSTANTS. Stick to snake_case for everything else or you're just asking for trouble. The offenders here are `:Code, :Definition`,  `@modName = locals[:moduleName]`.

Comment: @LesNightingill The Commands controller is in app/admin/commands.rb

Comment: @Code-Apprentice see updated html.erb block for your claification

Comment: in Rails, zeitwerk requires that the `CommandsController` is defined in `app/controllers/commands_controller.rb`. It *is* possible to work around it, but you're much better off to adhere to the "standard".

Comment: @LesNightingill I genuinely did not know that... thought activeadmin was supposed to be interceding, but I guess not. I've now added that controller, thank you, but the error persists: 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'

Comment: OK that's likely b/c `@command` is not defined (i.e. in the controller). If you put `Command.new`, it should work, or you could ensure that `@command` is defined in the controller like `@command=Command.new`. If you want the admin feature to be separated, like you had it, then look at the zeitwerk docs (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html)  for how to override the defaults.

Comment: @LesNightingill holy smokes Command.new, with your controller suggestion, totally working! f you wanna 'answer' this sucker i'll mark it, and thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the error messages, I conclude that:

1. `@command` is not defined. Because when you put `Command.new` in the view, the changed error message suggests that it fixes that particular problem. Revealing a different one! (So either put `Command.new` in the `form_for` helper, or define `@command = Command.new` in the controller.
2. The second problem (`CommandsController not defined`). Well Rails 7 has a particular way of organizing files, and it's pretty opinionated about that. It's implemented by the `zeitwerk` gem. You are urged to "fall-in" with the "Rails way", and put the `CommandsController` class in the app/controllers/commands_controller.rb file.

Comment: *googles how to upvote more than once